# How can I check if a webfont is free and available in browsers

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I am designing a web page and a client sent me the following request for the free web fonts available in the web:

Robot Condensed: 
    Vonnes Narroe Book

Source Sans Pro:
    Vonnes Narrow Book

Rufina:

Whitman Banner Bold
Source Serif Pro:

Georgia Regular

and here is a css class I use to add them:

```
.header-text-font-family{
font-family: "Whitman Ban Bd" !important;
}

.mainContainer {
 font-family: "Georgia Pro Reg" !important;
}
```

To be honest I never worked with these and when I apply them I cannot notice any changes in the web form.
Are they free fonts supported by browsers? Or better to ask How can I make sure they are free fonts available on the web?

Comment: you need to import the font in order to use it. you did that ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for answering what do you mean by import? Are they not free and available by default?

Comment: no they are not

Comment: So are they not free? or free but not available by default?

Comment: They are not available by default .. free or not, I don't know, but in all the cases you have to import them .. check the duplicate questions to know how

Comment: @TemaniAfif is there anyway I can check if they are free fonts or not?

Comment: you simply need to search them on the net ... if you find them so they  are free, if not you will get a way to buy them

Comment: You should definitelly check out Google Fonts. They have a wide collection of free and professional fonts which work perfectly on the web.

https://fonts.google.com

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bögözi. Very helpful. I think google does not support the fonts I need though. At least I could not find those there

Comment: @HamedMinaee You are welcome. You know, you could look for a "web-safe" substitute for your font, because not all fonts will work on the web and it can be pretty complicated to make them work. You complicate your life and it doesn't worth it. Cheers